# Azure DevOps Permission - allow a user to create work items but not edit source code?

Tags: azure-devops, permissions

We use Azure DevOps for source control.

I would like some users to be able to create work items, but not be able to make changes to source code for a specific project. It is ok for these users to be able to view / read the code, I just don't want them to be able to change it.

I've looked at the permission settings for groups in Azure DevOps, and read the Microsoft definitions of the permissions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-permissions.

Is it possible in an Azure DevOps project to set up a group that allows some users to create work items but not edit source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Create a new Group for these users, add this group to the Project scope "Readers" group

[image]

[image]

2.Make sure these users are not member or group member in "Contributors" group

[image]

3.Set the permission for this group to edit work items for Area Path in Project Settings -> Project configuration -> Security -> find the group. Check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-groups).

[image]

[image]